# creating funcionalities with flask

Tags: python, flask

I am creating a website with flask, python, postgres in which I have reached a point where I want a user already registered and logged in to be able to create a group of friends and place himself or herself as administrator of that specific group. I have tried to perform this action with flask-login as well as I did it with the initial creation user, but no idea or any route to follow does not work for me?

```
@ auth_bp.route ("/ Team_create /", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def Team_create_form ():
    
    form = CreateTeam ()
    Userl = User.query.all ()
    

    if form.validate_on_submit ():
         Teamname = form.Liga.data

teamm.save ()

        login_user (teamm, remember = True)
        next_page = request.args.get ('next', None)
        if not next_page or url_parse (next_page) .netloc! = '':
            next_page = url_for ('public.index')
        return redirect (next_page)
```

```
@ login_manager.user_loader
def load_user (Computer_id):
       
    return User.get_by_id (int (Computer_id))
```

```
class Teams (db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Teams'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = db.Column (db.Integer, primary_key = True)
def __init __ (self, ....)
 self.Teamname = Teamname

def __repr __ (self):
        return f '<Generalinf {self.Teamname}>'
    def save (self):
        if not self.id:
            db.session.add (self)
        db.session.commit ()
```

```
Could not build url for endpoint 'auth.pequipo'. Did you forget to specify values ​​['Teamname']?
```

```
@ auth_bp.route ("/ My_Team / <Teamname>")
def peteam (Teamname):

    invokers = Team.query.filter_by (Teamname = Teamname) .first_or_404 ()
    logo = Image (invokers.Teamlogo)
return render_template ("auth / player_interfaces / Team_i.html")
```

Comment: don't use spaces in urls - `"/Team_create/"`, `"/My_Team/<Teamname>"`, `"auth/player_interfaces/Team_i.html"`

Comment: there is good rule to use `CameCaseNames` only for classes but `lower_case_names` for variables like `def peteam(teamname):`,  `def team_create_form():` . See more [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)